# Access file from network share path in nodejs

Tags: node.js

The path looks like this

```
\\10.1.10.11\Results\\filename.rtf
```

From my machine, i can access it just fine by pasting it to `Run` box, enter username and password.

I've tried `smb2` ([smb2](https://github.com/bchelli/node-smb2)) but the sample code just hangs and after awhile, I get `Error: read ECONNRESET`.

I need to make this works on both linux and windows.

Comment: I too would like to know how to access files on a network share (using paths like you indicated).

Comment: @LonnieBest i use `smbmount` to mount the share folder and access it.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer. Anyone came to a conclusion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure I might as well just mount it and access it like local file.

for Linux server, I used `smbmount`.

Answer (score 24):

Did you escape the backslashes?

```js
 var path = "\\\\10.1.10.11\\Results\\filename.rtf";
 console.log(path);
```

Above works, but here's a better looking way (that accomplishes the same path without having to double up those backslashes):

```js
let path = String.raw`\\10.1.10.11\Results\filename.rtf`;
console.log(path);
```

**Warning:** With this technique, [you still have to double up the backslash if the string ends with a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416857/).

Doing this, I just had success attaching a file (located on a network share) to an email via node.js (and the nodemailer package). Perhaps this would apply in what you're doing too.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu try the `cifs-utils` package to mount the smb-cifs Windows file share to a Linux mount path

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD //192.168.1.88/shares /mnt/share
```

and then you can access it in this directory:  `/mnt/share`

In Windows you should be able to access the network path directly.  Windows 7 seems to accept forward slashes in place of back slashes for a network path name.  Try this:

```
var path = "//10.1.10.11/Results/filename.rtf";
```

Comment: When I try this on an Ubuntu server, I get: "Couldn't chdir to /mnt/share: No such file or directory"