# execute fs command within the context of a windows domain user

Tags: node.js, docker, fs

I have a nodejs docker container and I will access some windows file shares. The problem ist that I can't access the shares because of missing domain user rights / context. Is there a way to pass user credentials with the fs commands?

The workaround at the moment is to run nodejs server on windows machine. So the script gets the rights of the user who starts the server. I'am not happy with this solutions because I can't use docker.

Comment: You can do two things. 1. Run script with Administrator. 2. Give file access permission to user who run this script.

Comment: Sure. That's the workaround I currently using. But what coould solve the problem when I execute the script on a unix/linux system. Thanks!

Comment: May be you can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036886/access-file-from-network-share-path-in-nodejs

Comment: Thanks, mouting the drives on os first before accessing with nodejs could be an solution. I think there maybe is a smarter/faster way.