# Why can't String.raw end with a backslash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next, template-literals

[String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) can be used to create a string that contains backslashes, without having to double up those backslashes.

Historically, you'd need to double up backslashes when creating a string:

```js
let str = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip";
console.log(str);
```

String.raw allows your code to show the path without doubled backslashes:

```js
let str = String.raw`C:\Program Files\7-Zip`;
console.log(str);
```

The above code works fine, but today I discovered that it doesn't work if the raw string ends with a backslash:

```js
let str = String.raw`Can't End Raw With Backslash\`;
console.log(str);
```

The above snippet produces this error:

```
{
  "message": "SyntaxError: `` literal not terminated before end of script",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 14,
  "colno": 4
}
```

Why is this an exception?

**Update:** Another example where the single backslash doesn't do what I'd like is:

```js
let str1 = "folder";
let str2 = "subfolder";
let fileName = "file.txt"
let path = String.raw`\${str1}\${str2}\${fileName}`;
console.log(path);
```

While I was hoping for this output:

```
\folder\subfolder\file.txt
```

Instead it outputs:

```
\${str1}\${str2}\${fileName}
```

The backslash escapes the dollar sign's special meaning. So, this is yet another circumstance where you still have to double up those backslashes :(

Comment: Today I had a similar situation in python. [Python's implementation of raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) is better (for this use-case) than [EcmaScript's](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.raw) in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can, but remember that there's the "literal" character and the backslash character. You're asking for a *literal* backtick. Ask for a literal backslash:

```
let str = String.raw`...\\`;
```

Any character immediately following a backslash is treated as its literal version, regardless of what it is. `String.raw` can work around some of those limitations, but not all. It suppresses interpolation of things like `\n` but can't prevent you from accidentally adding a literal backtick.

Comment: I guess this is low-level parser baggage that `String.raw` couldn't overcome. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I think it's intentional. How else could you put a backtick in the string?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. It's a shame; until now, I thought I had found the perfect solution for not having to double up those backslashes. Too bad it comes with one gotcha.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a correct solution. `String.raw\`...\\\`` gives me `"...\\\\"`, not `"...\\"`.

Comment: @jtbandes You're misreading the output. When inside of double quotes the singular backslash must be escaped. Check with `console.log("...\\\\")`. If this was incorrect you'd actually see `"...\\\\\\\\"`. The string `"...\\"` actually contains a single backslash character.

Comment: I skipped a logical step in my previous comment — the OP's question was about how to create a string that ends with a **single** backslash. Your answer does show that `String.raw` can be used to create a string that ends with **two** backslashes, but at first glance it looks like you're saying that a trailing backslash can be escaped as \\, so `String.raw\`...\\\`` will create a string ending with one backslash. But it doesn't, and in fact there doesn't seem to be any way to do it with String.raw as far as I can tell... except perhaps `String.raw\`...${"\\"}\``

Answer (score 3):

Ending `` \` `` is always parsed as escaped `` ` `` symbol, meaning there's no matching closing backtick for a template literal. This makes it less consistent regarding how backslash can be used with `String.raw`.

For more special cases a string can be padded per need basis with characters that aren't expected in resulting sting.

It can be a newline:

```
const trimmedLine = (...args) => String.raw(...args).replace(/^(?:\r?\n|)([\s\S]*?)(?:\r?\n|)$/, '$1')

// "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\"
trimmedLine`
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
`
```

A space:

```
const trimmedSpace = (...args) => String.raw(...args).replace(/^([\s\S]*?) ?$/, '$1')

trimmedSpace`C:\Program Files\7-Zip\ `  // "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\" with no space
trimmedSpace`C:\Program Files\7-Zip\  ` // "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\ " with 1 space
```

And so on.

Even if a string shouldn't be trimmed, a helper can cover this by removing exactly one whitespace character, so extra one could be added to present in resulting string.